# Increment custom counter with standard sectioning command?

Tags: counters

My document is a (scr)book and I'm talking of parts and chapters here, but I think the underlying question is pretty generic.

- I want tables in the book to be enumerated continuously, in a chapter.table way.
- I reset the `chapter` counter for each part of the book using a custom-made `MyPart` command, which is necessary for several other reasons not presented here.
- However, **I do *not* want to reset the table numbering**. (I.e., the "chapter" part in the table number should keep a running total of chapters across part boundaries.)

I got it working by defining a counter `tabchapter`, and bumping that one manually whenever a new `\chapter` is declared. I wanted to avoid having to declare something like  `\MyChapter` solely for this purpose, but I was **not** satisfied with my solution:

```
\documentclass[open=any]{scrbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcounter{tabchapter}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\arabic{tabchapter}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand*{\tableformat}{Tab. \thetable}

%% Ugly hijacking of a formatting command to follow...
\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\addtocounter{tabchapter}{1}\Huge\bfseries}   %% <<----  *COUGH*...
    {}
    {0pt}
    {}

\newcommand{\MyPart}[1]{
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \refstepcounter{part}
}

\newcommand{\exampletable}[1]{
    \begin{table}
        \caption{#1}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            Nothing much.
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
}

\begin{document}
\MyPart{Book One}
\chapter{The First}
\exampletable{Some Table}
\chapter{The Second}
\exampletable{Other Table}
\MyPart{Book Two}
\chapter{The First of the Second}
\exampletable{Yet Another Table}
\end{document}
```

Is there another way to have some counter incremented whenever a **standard** sectioning command is called (i.e., somehow "linking" it to the standard counter)? *Other* than wrapping the bump in a custom `\MyChapter` command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need of **titlesec**

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\chapter}{\stepcounter{tabchapter}}
\newcounter{tabchapter}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\arabic{tabchapter}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand*{\tableformat}{Tab. \thetable}
```

Comment: That's it! That's *exactly* the thing I've been looking for! It struck me as so "unexotic" a requirement that there *had* to be a less hack-ish way to do it... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The [`chngcntr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) provides `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout` that you can use to add/remove elements that force counter resetting. You're probably after

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr
...
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}%
\counterwithout{table}{part}%
```

Comment: This will not number tables as <globalchapter>.<table>

Comment: Yes-ish... I *want* the running chapter total in the table number, i.e. akin to `chapter.table`, with resetting of `table` with each chapter. What I *don't* want is resetting the `chapter` part... but only for the purpose of table numbering. So I *do* need a custom counter of sorts, which gets incremented with each `\chapter`, but not reset with a new `\part` (or rather, `\MyPart`). But this package opens up several new ways to try it, so I'll see what inspiration brings up. ;-)

Comment: Oh, see what's going on now - it wasn't clear to me from reading the original question text. The MWE gives a better view of what is needed.