# How to create a new counter for an a new environment that is in sync with subsections

Tags: sectioning, numbering, environments, counters

I want to create an example environment with a counter which will be in sync with my subsections. So I'll have:

> subsection 3.2
>   lemma 3.2
>   example 3.2
>   example 3.3
>   lemma 3.3
>
> subsection 3.3
>   example 3.3
>   example 3.4

I find it hard to understand the `\newcounter` command and how it works. Plus, is there a command for `\onsectionchange` - so I can do (in pseudo code):

```
\onsubsectionchange{
%example counter := subsection counter
}
```

Comment: Be aware that even your minimal example has duplicate numbers for examples (example 3.3 in both subsection 3.2 and subsection 3.3). You have been warned. ;-)

Comment: You might want to check out my [somewhat related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30575/increment-custom-counter-with-standard-sectioning-command) and its answers, which might shed some light on the use of `\newcounter` and some of the things you can to to counters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `theorem` environment. Besides classical theorems, such numbered environments can be used for lemmas, definitions, examples, and more. So you don't have to take care of defining environments and counter adjustments.

A simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[subsection]
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\subsection{One}
\begin{example}
Text
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

There are various `theorem` packages which provides ways for customizing such numbered environments, see: [Theorem packages: which to use, which conflict](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5599/theorem-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict).

Comment: I tries this. The problem is that my Theorems are in italic and I want the Examples to be in plain text

Comment: No problem, just use any theorem package feature. Try: `\usepackage{amsthm}\theoremstyle{definition}` before your `\newtheorem{example}{Example}[subsection]`. And there are many ways for customizing font and structure.